# Centering item on (Bootstrap) responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to center a button on an image with responsive property. I'm using boostrap 3. Currently I've used CSS margin-left and margin-right to center but of course this is not efficient especially when viewed on smaller viewports.

Here's my CSS

```
    .gallery-list > li  .gallery-thumbnail i{
      top: 80px;
      color: red;
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 50px; 
      display:block;
      margin-left: 120px;
      background-color: transparent;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;    
    }

    .gallery-list > li:hover  .gallery-thumbnail i{
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;  
    }
```

Large screen display:
[image]

Small screen display:
[image]

So question is, how do I center the button irrespective of the device viewport?

Comment: Consider using http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net so people could experiment and provide answers much easier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

will not resolve the issue as the element is positioned absolutely. Please try the code below:

```
.gallery-list > li  .gallery-thumbnail {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
.gallery-list > li  .gallery-thumbnail i {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -25px; /* your icon height devided by 2 */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -21px; /* your icon width devided by 2 */
    font-size: 50px;
    color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.3s;  
            transition: all 0.3s;     
}
.gallery-list > li:hover  .gallery-thumbnail i{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's b/c your margin is not responsible. It uses absolute values; prefer :

```
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap's helper class `center-block`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center

Or just add

```
margin-left:auto; 
margin-right:auto;
```